# Question about some basic concepts

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

A $\pi-$system a closed under the formation of finite intersections, 
$$A,B\in\mathcal{P}\Rightarrow A\cap B\in\mathcal{P}$$
so is this implies that any field is a $\pi-$system, therefore a $\pi-$system is weaker than a field?

Comment: This is about [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets), not [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29), of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\pi$-system is strictly weaker than field (which is also closed under finite union and complement). For example the subsets of cardinality below a given threshold form a $\pi$-system, but not a field (if the base set is big enough).